# Mysterious failure removing nodes from an XML document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'd be surprised if anyone can explain this, but it'd be interesting to know if others can reproduce the weirdness I'm experiencing...

We've got a thing based on InfoPath that processes a lot of forms. Form data should conform to an XSD, but InfoPath keeps adding its own metadata in the form of so-called "my-fields". We would like to remove the my-fields, and I wrote this simple method:

```
string StripMyFields(string xml)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var matches = doc.SelectNodes("//node()").Cast<XmlNode>().Where(n => n.NamespaceURI.StartsWith("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/"));
    Dbug("Found {0} nodes to remove.", matches.Count());
    foreach (var m in matches)
        m.ParentNode.RemoveChild(m);

    return doc.OuterXml;
}
```

Now comes the really weird stuff! When I run this code it behaves as I expect it to, removing any nodes that are in InfoPath namespaces. However, if I comment out the call to Dbug, the code completes, but one "my-field" remains in the XML.

I've even commented out the content of the convenient Dbug method, and it still behaves this same way:

```
void Dbug(string s, params object[] args)
{
    //if (args.Length > 0)
    //    s = string.Format(s, args);
    //Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<skjema xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2008-03-03T22:25:25" xml:lang="en-us">
    <Field-1643 orid="1643">data.</Field-1643>
    <my:myFields>
        <my:field1>Al</my:field1>
        <my:group1>
            <my:group2>
                <my:field2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2009-01-01</my:field2>
                <Field-1611 orid="1611">More data.</Field-1611>
                <my:field3>true</my:field3>
            </my:group2>
            <my:group2>
                <my:field2>2009-01-31</my:field2>
                <my:field3>false</my:field3>
            </my:group2>
        </my:group1>
    </my:myFields>
    <Field-1612 orid="1612">Even more data.</Field-1612>
    <my:field3>Blah blah</my:field3>
</skjema>
```

The "my:field3" element (at the bottom, text "Blah blah") is not removed unless I invoke Dbug.

Clearly the universe is not supposed to be like this, but I would be interested to know if others are able to reproduce.

I'm using VS2012 Premium (11.0.50727.1 RTMREL) and FW 4.5.50709 on Win8 Enterprise 6.2.9200.

Comment: `XmlDocument` is not `LINQ`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek LINQ is used here for processing nodes of XmlDocument (yep, very weird)

Comment: Correct, but I also use LINQ (Where). Since I've no idea where the error originates, I tagged it with both.

Comment: @thedag: I formatted your Xml fragment. As any other code snippet, simply indent the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: Ah - I made a small change which does seem to indicate the problem is related to LINQ. I changed the Dbug call so it doesn't invoke the Count() extension (just put a constant there), and then the last field is never removed!

Comment: `Count` call initiates lazy collection enumeration; try to add `ToList()` in the end of your linq query.

Comment: @Tommi I'm not modifying the collection I'm iterating over. I'm modifying objects in that collection, and there is nothing wrong with doing so. :)

Comment: Sorry, I modified previous comment right before you post yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first. LINQ uses concept known as [*deferred execution*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx). This means no results are fetched until you actually *materialize query* (for example via enumeration).

Why would it matter with your nodes removal issue? Let's see what happens in your code:

1. `SelectNodes` creates `XPathNodeIterator`, which is used by `XPathNavigator` which feeds data to `XmlNodeList` returned by `SelectNodes`
2. `XPathNodeIterator` walks xml document tree basing on XPath expression provided
3. The `Cast` and `Where` simply decide whether node returned by `XPathNodeIterator` should participate in final result

We arrive right before `DBug` method call. For a moment, assume it's not there. At this point, **nothing** have actually happened just yet. We only got *unmaterialized* LINQ query.

Things change when we start iterating. All the iterators (`Cast` and `Where` got their own iterators too) start rolling. `WhereIterator` asks `CastIterator` for item, which then asks `XPathNodeIterator` which finally returns first node (`Field-1643`). Unfortunately, this one fails the `Where` test, so we ask for next one. More luck with `my:myFields`, it is a match - we remove it.

We quickly proceed to `my:field1` (again, *WhereIterator* → *CastIterator* → *XPathNodeIterator*), which is also removed. Stop here for a moment. Removing `my:field1` detaches it from its parent, which results in setting its (`my:field1`) siblings to `null` (there's no other nodes before/after removed node).

What's the current state of things? `XPathNodeIterator` knows its current element is `my:field1` node, which just got removed. Removed as in *detached from parent*, but iterator still holds reference. Sounds great, let's ask it for next node. What `XPathNodeIterator` does? Checks its `Current` item, and asks for `NextSibling` (since it has no children to walk first) - which is `null`, given we just performed detachment. And this means iteration is over. Job done.

As a result, by altering collection structure during iteration, you only removed two nodes from your document (while in reality only one, as the second removed node was child of the one already removed).

Same behavior can be observed with much simpler XML:

```
<Root>
    <James>Bond</James>
    <Jason>Bourne</Jason>
    <Jimmy>Keen</Jimmy>
    <Tom />
    <Bob />
</Root>
```

Suppose we want to get rid of nodes starting with `J`, resulting in document containing only honest man names:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var matches = doc
    .SelectNodes("//node()")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(n => n.Name.StartsWith("J"));

foreach (var node in matches)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
```

Unfortunately, *Jason* and *Jimmy* remain. *James*' next sibling (the one to be returned by iterator) was originally meant to be *Jason*, but as soon as we detached *James* from tree there's no siblings and iteration ends.

Now, why it works with `DBug`? `Count` call materializes query. Iterators have run, we got access to all nodes we need when we start looping. The same things happens with `ToList` called right after `Where` or if you *inspect* results during debug (VS even notifies you inspecting results will enumerate collection).

Comment: My only problem with this explanation is that SelectNodes doesn't merely return an iterator - it returns XmlNodeList. Now I'm thinking the list must have been initialized only with an iterator. I was aware that LINQ statements return expression trees, but I thought the node list had been fully constructed by SelectNodes, and then I certainly would not expect the behavior I see here.

Comment: @TheDag: that's correct and that's what I wrote. Iterator is used internally by returned `XmlNodeList`. When you think about it you can break any modifiable collection when you alter its structure during enumeration. Some manifest it better (for example, `List<T>` will throw exception), other worse.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is down to the schrodinger's cat problem that Where will not actually compile the results of the query until you view or act upon it. Meaning, until you call Count() (or any other function for getting the results) or view it in debugger, the results don't exist. As a test, try put it as such:

```
if (matches.Any())
    foreach (var m in matches)
        m.ParentNode.RemoveChild(m);
```

Comment: I think you're onto something. Anything that causes the collection to be enumerated before we start modifying the document (such as using ToList() or invoking Count()) causes it to behave as expected. If the predicate was actually selecting nodes, I think this might make sense, but here the predicate is just saying if a node is in a particular namespace or not, and I can't quite understand what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, its only when you actually view the results while debugging that it removes the last node. Incidentally, converting the result to a List and then looping through it also works.

```
List<XmlNode> matches = doc.SelectNodes("//node()").Cast<XmlNode>().Where(n =>   n.NamespaceURI.StartsWith("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/")).ToList();
        foreach (var m in matches)
        {
            m.ParentNode.RemoveChild(m);
        }
```

Comment: ToList() causes the collection to be enumerated, and this must somehow be the key to what's going on. In the original code, we modify the document between (implicit) calls to Enumerator.MoveNext(), but with ToList() we're forcing enumeration of the entire collection without modifying the document. However, I still don't understand what's going on, since we never modify the collection that is being enumerated. To my mind, the fact that we modify the document ought to be irrelevant.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the two my:field3 elements. Before enumeration, it might be holding one reference to both elements. But when we force enumeration, it actually creates seperate references to these two elements. Will Try changing the last my:field3 element to my:field4 and re-run against your original code, just to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

jimmy_keen's solution worked for me. I had just a simple

```
//d is an XmlDocument
XmlNodeList t = d.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode x in t)
{
    x.ParentNode.RemoveChild(x);
}
d.Save(outputpath);
```

this would remove only 3 nodes while stepping through in debug mode would remove 1000+ nodes.

Just adding a Count before the foreach solved the problem:

var count = t.Count;